# For What Inputs Should I Define Rules In Model Class?

Tags: php, yii, yii-validation

Should I define rules for all of input elements in a model class?
For example the model form has 2 input type element and a textarea.
Can I just define rules for those two input type and not for textarea ?

I have done so but the text entered inside the textarea isn't save but if I put a rule for example for its length it will be saved.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't define any rules for an attribute (or define an `unsafe` rule), that attribute will not be set during mass-assignment (`$model->attributes = $_POST['ModelClassName']`). That  seems like the most likely reason why your textarea value doesn't get saved. See [Securing attribute assignments](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model#securing-attribute-assignments).

---

Yii documentation suggests only creating rules for the fields that take user input. However, I found it useful to specify rules for all attributes, both based on business logic and underlying database storage (although I do not like the fact that the same class has to worry about both of these aspects), and then adding `unsafe` rules to the fields where mass-assignment should not be allowed.